# a and b are integers where gcd(a,b)=p which is a prime. find gcd(a^2,b^2).

Tags: prime-numbers

> **Problem 5** (10 points): Let $a,b$ be integers such that $g.c.d.(a,b) = p$ where $p$ is prime.  Find $g.c.d.(a^2,b^2)$.

[(Original screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHGHh.png)

I've found that $g.c.d. (a^2,b^2) = p^2$ when using examples for $(a,b)$ like $(9,12)$, $(34,85)$, and $(14,21)$ whose gcd's are primes. I could put my answer down as  $g.c.d. (a^2,b^2) = p^2$ and probably get the answer right but I would really like to find that through proofs rather than examples. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By squaring a and b, you do not introduce any additional prime factors.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, let $(a,b)=p$ where $p$ is a positive integer and $\displaystyle \frac aA=\frac bB=p\implies (A,B)=1$

So, $\displaystyle(a^n,b^n)=(p^nA^n,p^nB^n)=p^n(A^n,B^n)$

As $A,B$ are coprime, so will be $A^n,B^n$

$\displaystyle\implies(a^n,b^n)=(a,b)^n$

Comment: What does $A,B$ and $A^n, B^n$ being coprime have to do with the assumption $(a^n,b^n)=(a,b)^n$? I understand everything else.

Comment: @magnuspaajarvi, We have $$(a^n,b^n)=p^n(A^n,B^n)=p^n=(a,b)^n$$